# Use wordpress api in parent site

Tags: php, wordpress

I have the following site structure
Parent Site
-> blog (wordpress)
     -> get-recent-posts.php
-> index.php

I want to display a list of recent posts in the index.php. I am trying to use wordpress api functions in index.php but it is not working. If i try to directly run get-recent-posts.php it shows the posts but if i include it in index.php it does'nt work.

Comment: What does that mean "not working" and "doesn't work"? Any concrete problems?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding the following code to the top of the page will do the job. The path should be the absolute or relative path to your wp installation.

```
<?php 
require_once '.blog/wp-load.php';
>
```

Answer (score 0):

please be more specific , i personally don't understand what you mean by the following

```
Parent Site -> blog (wordpress) -> get-recent-posts.php -> index.php
```

if you want the following setup

```
http://yoursite.com ( where you can access Wordpress functions )
http://yoursite.com/wordpress ( where your blog resides )
```

maybe this will help:
http://codex.wordpress.org/Giving_WordPress_Its_Own_Directory